# Using luxon and `sorter:"date"` in Tabulator - Uncaught ReferenceError: luxon is not defined

Tags: javascript, tabulator, luxon

Using Tabulator 5.4, and trying to allow the user to sort a column that contains dates, I am told in the documentation that

> Dependency Required You will need to include the luxon.js library to
> use this sorter

but the documentation doesn't explain *how* to include the luxon.js library.

I have installed luxon using

```
npm install luxon
```

and I have

```
import {TabulatorFull as Tabulator} from 'tabulator-tables'
import { DateTime } from "luxon"
```

and then, in the table definition:

```
            {title: 'Modified', field: 'modifiedTime', sorter:"date", cssClass: 'grey'},
```

but when I run this, I get:

```
datetime.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: luxon is not defined
    at Sort.datetime$2 (datetime.js:3:30)
    at Sort.date$1 (date.js:9:18)
    at Sort._sortRow (Sort.js:462:37)
    at Sort.js:434:19
    at Array.sort (<anonymous>)
    at Sort._sortItems (Sort.js:428:8)
    at Sort.sort (Sort.js:369:10)
    at RowManager.refreshPipelines (RowManager.js:723:40)
    at VirtualDomVertical.rerenderRows (VirtualDomVertical.js:98:4)
    at RowManager.reRenderInPosition (RowManager.js:849:18)
```

I assume that I am not installing luxon in the right place or in the right way.  How should I do it?

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not help.  Same error as before.

Comment: Use `import * as luxon from 'luxon'` and attach the luxon variable to `Window` object using `window.luxon = luxon`

Answer (score 7):

As [Timur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15048478/timur) suggested, this will work:

```
import {DateTime} from 'luxon'
window.DateTime = DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Nigel and @Timur's suggestions, note that if you are using Typescript, the addition of the two lines will fail to compile with the error `Property 'DateTime' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'`.  To work around this, you need to create a type file (e.g. `src/types/index.d.ts`) and add the following to it:

```
export {}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    DateTime: any 
  }
}
```